# Traits that improve Abjuration school spells

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

Are there any [Traits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits) that would benefit a caster focusing on the Abjuration school?

Character design is a buffing support. Classes are [Bard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard) and he will be Prestiging into the Abjurant Champion from Complete mage (3.5)

I have not been able to locate any guides that have any abjuration specific traits. I have found traits that are useful to all casters but my focus is on the abjuration school.

Comment: Show 2500 traits per page and ctrl+f "abjuration" yields nothing, so probably no, but then again, you probably already know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there do not appear to be abjuration-specific traits, there are two traits that give small bonuses to a chosen school of magic, and you *could* select Abjuration for them. I say 'could' because frankly they don't sound very useful to me. Nonetheless, here they are:

**Shrouded Casting -** You can cast spells from that school as if you had the Eschew Materials feat. (http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/shrouded-casting)

**Magical Flair** - You can cause spells you cast (of the chosen school) to manifest with strange visual, auditory, or olfactory features that make them hard to identify. (http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-flair)

Comment: Magical Flair seems particularly suited for a bard.  Fluff-wise, it's perfect, allowing you to put whatever spins on your spells you want to make them look and sound impressive.  Mechanically, unless the opponent wants to spend three turns concentrating on *detect magic* to try again (if that even works, I'm not looking at rules atm), they need to be making their Spellcraft checks if they want to know what buffs you're throwing on your teammates.  The difference between a Mage Armor and a Resistance to Fire is huge when you're guessing whether to attack with magic or steel.

Comment: @gatherer818 I agree that it's some quality fluff for a buffing bard, but mechanically a +2 increase in the DC to identify your spells just isn't that much - I would expect most enemies that have Spellcraft at all to have enough that it doesn't make a difference. And we do have the 'optimization' tag in play here. Magical Flair is fun, but optimal... probably not.

Comment: Fair point, I missed that tag.  I still really like that trait, though.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no traits that improve abjurations.

Though there are (several of each kind) traits that improve one of the following:

- [Dispel check](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/scorned-by-magic)
- [Caster level](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/outcast-s-intuition) vs [dispel chec](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/resilient-caster)k
- [Caster level](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/cross-disciplined) for [particular](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/gifted-adept) [spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/transmuter-magic)
- [Initiative](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/combat-traits/excitable)

Of those, dispel check bonus is the most abjuration-specific bonus of the list.